# How to implement Ajax on views form

Tags: views, forms, ajax

In a view such as what you find at /admin/content

The is a form on the view to delete, publish etc. Is it possible to Ajaxify so that the form will submit and the view will refresh.

Comment: try [turning on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByUii.png) Ajax in the views settings.

Comment: Not quite what I was trying to achieve, turning on ajax in the view will work for exposed filters and paging. It won't work when the view contains a form that acts on the content within it. (eg one provided in core at /admin/content)